Populate non ascii password in a file using puppet
I am trying to populate a password with non ascii characters into a template file using puppet. I have ecoded password with non ascii to base64 and placed it in hiera-esecrets. When I try to decode the password in template it was not working.
puppet
    class abc::container ( 
     $key_encrypt       = hiera('abc::configs::key_encrypt', undef), ){
    @docker_container { "${app}:${version}":     

   files                 => {       
   'configuration.properties'    => {         
   destination                   => '/opt/configuration.properties',         
    mount_mode                   => 'rw',         
    owner                        => 'root',         
    group                        => 'root',         
    mode                         => '0755',         
    content                      => template('abc/configuration.properties.erb'),       },     }, }


configuration.properties.erb
<% 
require 'base64' 
key_encrypt = @key_encrypt key_encrypt_d = Base64.decode64(key_encrypt) 
%> 
master.key.2024-08-22-02-05=<%= @key_encrypt_d %>

Below is the error when puppet gets executed
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse inline template: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
All I see is the base64 encoded value in the template file. I want to get the actual password.

It sounds like your data are not being correctly decoded.  "hiera-esecrets" is not meaningful to me or to Google, but I speculate that you are trying to use Hiera's eyaml back end.  If so, then the error suggests that you are using it incorrectly.  This previous answer of mine might be useful to you in that regard, but if you want us to evaluate what you're doing then we'll need more information about exactly what that is.  Hiera configuration, steps to record the encrypted data, etc..

What about encoding it in before hand and then decoding in puppet as mentioned in this comment
